# keypress not working in chrome or firefox

Tags: javascript, html

```
function firstname()
{
var x=document.forms["frm"]["fname"].value;
if(x=="")
 {  
    document.getElementById("checkfname").value = " First Name required";
  return false;
}
 else
 {
 document.getElementById("checkfname").value = "";
return true;
}
 }
<html>
<body>
 <form method="post" name="frm">
 <input type="text" name="fname" onkeypress="firstname()" onkeydown="firstname()"      onkeyup="firstname()"/>
 <input name="checkfname"/>
 </body>
 </html>
```

cant get the function run at all in chrome or Firefox?? it isn't firing up. Any help pls?

Comment: For one, the JS should be between `<script>` tags.

Comment: Are you implying it works in IE, Opera and Safari ?

Comment: Looking at the code, it doesn't work anywhere, you have names on the elements, and are trying to access those names with `getElementById`, which suprisingly gets an element by ***ID*** ?

Comment: i did use the script tags. this is just a sample of the code. thanx for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make sure you have javascript code inside the script tag and then

you are using `document.getElementById("checkfname")` but you haven't give `checkfname` as Id of any element. So it's gonna be undefined element so change it like this

```
<input id="checkfname"/>
```

and then try your code.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GwaxS/)